# Open sets in the order topology

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

I'm having trouble understanding the order topology. If we consider $R_{\ge 0} \times R_{\ge 0}$ given the order topology coming from the lexicographic order, my understanding is that the sets $[2,3] \times (2,3)$, $(2,3) \times [2,3]$, $(2,3) \times (2,3)$ are all open. For the set $[2,3] \times (2,3)$, for any $\langle x,y \rangle \in [2,3] \times (2,3)$, the nbhd $((x,\dfrac{2+y}{2}),(y,\dfrac{3+y}{2})) \subset [2,3]\times(2,3)$ and contains points $p,q$ such that $p < \langle x,y\rangle < q$. Thus, the set $[2,3] \times (2,3)$ is open. $(2,3) \times [2,3]$ and $(2,3)\times(2,3)$ follow by similar logic. However, the set $[0,2) \times [0,\infty)$ is not open because there does not exist a open nbhd around $\langle 0,0\rangle$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. The order topology is defined on totally ordered sets. $R_{\ge 0} \times R_{\ge 0}$ is not a priori totally ordered, the total orders of the factors just induce a *partial* order on the product. 

So my question is: What total order are you considering on $R_{\ge 0} \times R_{\ge 0}$?

Comment: @Ingix, given two totally ordered setd, it is possible to define another totally ordered set on the product; namely the [lexicographic order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). I guess the OP is considering that order on $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: @Dog_69 Thanks for the help. That order makes the statements correct, but the example given in the proof incorrect. I'd rather explain the correct/incorrect statements when I know the OP's used order instead of speculating. Lexicographical order would make sense, though.

Comment: @Ingix I didn't see the order used in the OP's question. But I think you're right. It's better to wait for a clarification.

Comment: @Dog_69, I do indeed mean the lexicographic order — sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @selfstudy Don't worry. But, in that case, make sure there is no typo in your question, as user Ingix suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a great question for increasing your understanding of the lexicographic order. To recall, in this order, $(a,b) < (c,d)$ if and only if either $a<c$ or $a=c$ and $b<d$. (This is exactly how we sort words when alphabetizing, for example in a dictionary—hence the name "lexicographic".)

So for your first remark: it's not actually true (when $x\ne y$) that
$$
\bigg(\bigg(x,\dfrac{2+y}{2}\bigg),\bigg(y,\dfrac{3+y}{2}\bigg)\bigg) \subset [2,3]\times(2,3).
$$
Take for example $x=2.1$ and $y=2.4$. Note that every single element of the form $(2.3,z)$ for $z\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ is in the interval $\big( (2.1,2.2), (2.4,2.7) \big)$. In particular, $(2.3,4)$ is in that interval, but is not in $[2,3]\times(2,3)$.

A modification of your idea works, however: any $(x,y) \in [2,3]\times(2,3)$ is contained in the neighborhood
$$
\bigg(\bigg(x,\dfrac{2+y}{2}\bigg),\bigg(x,\dfrac{3+y}{2}\bigg)\bigg) \subset [2,3]\times(2,3)
$$
(note the single difference). Another way of phrasing this idea: an arbitrary union of open sets is always open, and
$$
[2,3]\times(2,3) = \bigcup_{x\in[2,3]} \big( \{x\}\times(2,3) \big)
$$
where each $\{x\}\times(2,3)$ is open by the above argument.

The same argument (almost exactly) shows that $(2,3)\times(2,3)$ is also an open set in the lexicographic topology.

On the other hand, $(2,3) \times [2,3]$ is *not* an open set, because it does not contain a neighborhood of $(2.9,2)$ (for example). The elements "just less than" $(2.9,2)$ are of the form $(2.9,y)$ where $y$ is just less than $2$—and no such elements are in $(2,3) \times [2,3]$.

It turns out that the set $[0,2) \times [0,\infty)$ is in fact open. Can you prove this using these ideas?

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing why $[0,2) \times [0,\infty)$ is open. I can see that the set contains a neighborhood for all points that are not $(0,0)$. However, for the point $(0,0)$, is the neighborhood simply $((0,0), (0, \epsilon))$ for some $\epsilon$?

Comment: Note that $v \notin (v,w)$, so that can't be exactly right. However, note that $[ (0,0), (0,\varepsilon) )$ is actually an open set in this topology! The reason boils down to the fact that in the topological space $X=\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ (with the usual topology, namely the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$), the set $[0,1)$ is actually an open set, even though "we can see a space that $X$ sits in" and "$[0,1)$ doesn't look open". Do you agree?

Comment: Got it — this makes sense now! Thank you.